# Create 3-layer dynamic option list using javascript while the options are query from DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I want to display a 3-layer dynamic option list on an ejs page.

The second layer options change depending on the first layer.
The third layer options change depending on the second layer.

```
 <form>
                platform
                <select id="list1"></select>
                
                style
                <select id="list2"></select>
                
                number
                <select id="list3"></select>
</form>
```

I found code which can complete this task, but the options' data are written in javascript.

In my situation, options are queries from mongoDB. So I can't construct options by writing var in javascript.

The data are stored like down below in MongoDB:

```
[
  {
   platform: 'aaa',
   style: 'cool',
   number: [ '4' ],
  },
  {
   platform: 'aaa',
   style: 'bright',
   number: [ '2', '6' ],
  },
  {
   platform: 'bbb',
   style: 'dark',
   number: [ '6', '8' ],
  },
  {
   platform: 'aaa',
   style: 'chill',
   number: [ '3' ],
  }
]
```

Therefore,

the first layer contains 2 options: ['aaa','bbb' ]

the second layer contains (3, 1) options: [['cool', 'bright', 'chill'], ['dark'] ]

the third layer contains ( (1,2,1) , (2) ) options:[ [ ['4'],['2', '6'],['3'] ] , ['6', '8']]

For example,

When I select 'aaa' in the first layer, I can choose one from ['cool','bright','chill'].

If I choose 'bright' in the second layer, I can choose one from ['2', '6'] in the third layer.

I transfer the data structure of options from mongoDB in nodejs but they turn into **string** when res.render them to ejs.

How can I construct a 3-layer dynamic option list while the options are query from DB?